# How do I create a chapter name for only an instance

Tags: sectioning, formatting, chapters, titles

So I have this chapter name for which I have as standard:

```
Chapter 1
Chapter 2
Chapter 3
```

But I want to have a completely different chapter name which would be called: `Category`

And it would be co-existing with the other chapter names without changing anything like here:

```
Chapter 1
Chapter 2 
Chapter 3+4
Category
Chapter 9
```

Here's my code and attempt:

```
%% document class and packages
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%% titlesec
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
    {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
    {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter: }
    {0em}
    {\centering} 
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-40pt}{20pt}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}

%% Attempt to make a command
\newcommand\categorychapter{\setchapter{Chủ đề:}}
%% Default chapter settings
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Bài}}
\linespread{1.05}
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}

\chapter{Second Chapter}

%% Double numbered chapter
\label{single}
\let\oldchapter\thechapter
\def\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}\texttt{+}\the\numexpr\value{chapter}+1\relax}
\chapter{Chapter three plus four}

%% Chapter returning to normal numbering after skipping a number
\label{double}
\let\thechapter\oldchapter
\refstepcounter{chapter}
\refstepcounter{chapter}
\chapter{Chapter six}

%% Regular chapter without any alterations
\chapter{Chapter seven}

%% Attempt at a special chapter
\categorychapter{Category Chapter}
%% Radically different chapter numbering 
\setcounter{chapter}{11}
\chapter{Chapter twelve}
```

Comment: Unless titlesec redefines it, `\chaptername` **is** `Chapter`.  Anyway, what you really need is `\renewcommand{\chapapp}{Category}` or `\newcommand{\categoryname}{Category}` and `\let\chapapp=\categoryname`.  `\chapapp` is used for both `\chaptername` and `\appendixname`.

Comment: Well the `\atbegindocument` overrides the normal formatting with the title Bài

Comment: I find find using titlesec to be far more complicated than not using titlesec. I can show you how to do it that way, but not the other.

Comment: So you will do it but without using titlesec right? also see my edit for cleaner code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but using `\chapter*{Category}` might just solve it?

```
%% document class and packages
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}

\chapter{Second Chapter}

%% Double numbered chapter
\label{single}
\let\oldchapter\thechapter
\def\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}\texttt{+}\the\numexpr\value{chapter}+1\relax}
\chapter{Chapter three plus four}

%% Chapter returning to normal numbering after skipping a number
\label{double}
\let\thechapter\oldchapter
\refstepcounter{chapter}
\refstepcounter{chapter}
\chapter{Chapter six}

%% Regular chapter without any alterations
\chapter{Chapter seven}

%% Attempt at a special chapter
\chapter*{Category Chapter}
%% Radically different chapter numbering 
\setcounter{chapter}{11}
\chapter{Chapter twelve}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: NB: This also works when you want to have the same, but then for sections, subsections and subsubsections. So, `\section*{bla}`, `\subsection*{bla}`, `\subsubsection*{bla}`